# How to find duplicate count among several columns?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here is a sample table that mimics my scenario:

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4   LAST_COL
A       P       X       NY      10
A       P       X       NY      11
A       P       Y       NY      12
A       P       Y       NY      13
A       P       X       NY      14
B       Q       X       NY      15
B       Q       Y       NY      16
B       Q       Y       CA      17
B       Q       Y       CA      18
```

The LAST_COL is a primary key so it will be different every time.

I want to ignore LAST_COL and gather some statistics related to the rest of the 4 columns.

Basically, I have millions of rows in my table, and I want to know which set of `COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 and COL_4` are having most number of rows.

So, I want a query which can output me all the unique rows with their count of occurrences.

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   COL_4   TOTAL
A       P       X       NY      3
A       P       Y       NY      2
B       Q       X       NY      1
B       Q       Y       NY      1
B       Q       Y       CA      2
```

Thanks to anyone who helps me with this.

*I am using MS SQL, if that would make any difference.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the solution should be scalable to several columns. The example in the question was for simplicity, but I have like 6 to 7 columns on which I want to run a statistic query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
```

If you ever want to weed out rows that don't have a duplicate:

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The **GROUP BY** is what you want here. For example:

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly all you need is something like:

```
SELECT COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM table
GROUP BY COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4
```

Answer (score 1):

> are having most number of rows

So you want to count, and then ORDER BY the count DESC

```
SELECT    COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*) COUNT_ROWS
FROM      TBL
GROUP BY  COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
ORDER BY  COUNT_ROWS DESC
```