# Find total duplicate entries on two columns

Tags: mysql

I need to get the TOTAL number of entries that contain duplicate data for multiple columns. It is exactly the same thing being done on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160058/how-to-find-duplicate-count-among-several-columns) page where he has,

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

EXCEPT, I need sum(COUNT()). I have tried doing sum, and removing the group by clause, but I continue to get errors.

Comment: I doubt you need sum(count(*)) - the query you have looks correct

Comment: The query I have gives me the number of each duplicate occurrence. I need the total number of duplicate occurrences through out all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making your grouped count a sub-query:

```
SELECT sum(sub.counts) FROM (
  SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*) as counts
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sub;
```

The most important thing really is to give the original 'COUNT(*)' a name so you can reference it easily in the outer query.

Comment: +1, this will work, except every subquery needs its own alias, fixed it for ya.

Comment: I feel like I should have thought of that with the subquery needing its own alias. I kept getting that same error. This is perfect now. Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot about the subquery alias - I tested it in sqlite (not needed there) as my machine with mysql wasn't switched on. Thanks Johan!

Answer (score 1):

You can have both results by using `with rollup`

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4 WITH ROLLUP
HAVING cnt > 1
```

The last row will be yield the grand total.

```
SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4 WITH ROLLUP
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY (COL_1 IS NOT NULL) ASC
```

This will yield the same result, but with the grand total as the first row.

Comment: Great answer also Johan. Thanks.