# how to get row count in a table of different types in one table within same query

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example,the table contains the column `jobtype`, the thing is we need to count no. of rows of same `jobtype` and at the same time for all the jobs in same query.

Comment: same jobs types means duplicates ?

Comment: please post some sample data, expected output and current query (if you have one).

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
select jobtype, count(*) from your_table group by jobtype 
  union 
select 'My Total', count(*) from your_table;
```

This will give result like(based on your table):

```
IT         5
Admin      10
Myv Total  15
```

Comment: It won't give you a total, though.

Comment: That was fine,but actually i want is that there are different subjects under one jobtype,i need the count of the subjects of that jobtype

Comment: I think you need to update your question with table examples.

Comment: job type='engineer'  under this jobtype,there are subjects below     maths,social,science,gk...etc                                      THe output should be jobtype=engineer          maths-10                                  science-20                  social-15                                     gk-25                                                these are  all the no of questions under the jobtype 'engineer'

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 int variables

```
$SQL = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
$jobLookingFor = 'programmer';
$jobTypeSameCount = 0;
$jobTotalNumber = 0;

while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($SQL))
{
  if($result['jobtype'] === $jobLookingFor)
  {
    $jobTypeSameCount = $jobTypeSameCount + 1;
  }

  $jobTotalNumber = $jobTotalNumber + 1;
}
```

That is off the top of my head, so excuse the spelling mistakes.

after the while loop has completed
the jobTypeSameCount will be the number of the same jobs you are searching for
the jobTotalNumber will be the total rows including both the similar and other job type rows.

**EDIT: Try this solution from a simillar question**

SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4

If you ever want to weed out rows that don't have a duplicate:

SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

at: [How to find duplicate count among several columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160058/how-to-find-duplicate-count-among-several-columns)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS same_duplicate_jobs ,job_type ,total_jobs = ( SELECT    COUNT(*) FROM      jobs) FROM      jobs GROUP BY  job_type HAVING    COUNT(*) > 1
```